# Eloquent: MySqlConnection could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following piece of Laravel Code:

```
public function remove($user_id)
    {
        //$result = $this->where('id','=',$user_id)->delete();

        DB::transaction(function($user_id)
        {
            $item_subscriber = new ItemSubscriber();
            $result = $this->where('id','=',$user_id)->delete();
            $result = $item_subscriber->where('user_id','=',$user_id)->delete();


        });
    }
```

I am not getting clue the reason of this error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found out the mistake I was doing;I was not using **use** to pass parameter.

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($user_id)
        {
            $item_subscriber = new ItemSubscriber();
            $result = $this->where('id','=',$user_id)->delete();
            $result = $item_subscriber->where('user_id','=',$user_id)->delete();
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. Strange that it worked on local development but not on live server.